# Generating 3D point cloud with predicted Depths

Tags: opencv, point-clouds, color-depth

I was trying to generate a 3D point cloud (PC) from an image with predicted depths. The camera intrinsics and the ground truth depth images are given. Firstly, I am generating a PC with the GT depth using the camera intrinsic and it looks like this:
[image: PC with GT Depths]

But, when I try to generate the PC for the same image with the predicted depths, the PC looks weird. Here is the PC with the predicted depths:
[image: PC with Predicted Depths]

I am using the same camera intrinsics for doing this. I am using the same code and procedure for both the PC generations. I was expecting two PCs to be close but what I am getting is really weird. What am I doing wrong?

My code for generating the point cloud is as follows:

```
int rows = RGB.size[0];
int cols = RGB.size[1];
for (int v = 0; v < rows; v++) {
    for (int u = 0; u < cols; u++) {
        auto z = depth.at<ushort>(v, u) / 5000;
        auto x = (u - intrinsics.cx) * z / intrinsics.fx;
        auto y = (v - intrinsics.cy) * z / intrinsics.fy; 

        // std::cout<<"x = "<< x << " y = " << y <<std::endl;
        point3d << x, y, z;
        pc.vertices.push_back(point3d);
        pc.colors.push_back(RGB.at<cv::Vec3b>(v, u));

    }
}
```

The GT depth image:
[image: GT Depth Image]
The predicted depth image:
[image: Predicted Depth Image]

Edit: I found the mistake. The depth values were scaled by 5000. So, I missed that part and didn't divide the value of z while constructing the point cloud. After dividing by 5000, the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The depth value should have been divided by 5000 while constructing the 3D scene as the depth values were scaled by 5000 originally.

For details [The camera intrinsics and guide on how to construct the 3D point cloud](https://vision.in.tum.de/data/datasets/rgbd-dataset/file_formats#intrinsic_camera_calibration_of_the_kinect)